# If every prime ideal is a contracted ideal, does it imply that the induced map between spectrums is surjective?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism between commutative rings with identity. Then there exists an induced map $f' : Spec(B) \rightarrow Spec(A)$. If $f'$ is surjective, then clearly every prime ideal of $A$ is a contracted ideal. Now my question is, is the converse true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $A$, and suppose that
$P=f^{-1}(I)$ where $I$ is some ideal of $B$.
Let $S=A-P$, a multiplicatively closed subset
of $A$, and $T=f(S)$. Then $T$ is a multiplicatively
closed subset of $B$ and is disjoint from $I$.
By Zorn's lemma, there is an ideal $Q$ of $B$
maximal with respect to the conditions that $Q$
contains $I$ and $Q$ is disjoint from $T$. By
a standard argument, $Q$ is prime. Moreover $f^{-1}(Q)=P$.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification!

Answer (score 0):

By atiyah-macdonald thm 3.15
If there is an homomorphism from A to B and p^{ec}=p, then p is a contraction of a prime ideal of B.

In your question p is contracted ideal, so p satisfies p^{ec}=p