# If the localization of a ring is a field, then the ring is an integral domain?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $D$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $R$. Is it the case that if $D^{-1}R$ is a field, then $R$ must be an integral domain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not true, one reason being that [being an integral domain is not a local property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685844/is-being-an-integral-domain-a-local-property).
For a concrete example take $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, this is not an integral domain, but if we localise at the set $\{ 1, 3, 5\} = \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \setminus (2)$ we obtain a finite integral domain and hence a field.
You can find some details about determining this localisation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32381/localization-of-a-prime-ideal-in-mathbbz-6-mathbbz).

Comment: Wait, all those elements are already units, so won't that just give back the original ring?

Comment: 3 isn't a unit!

Comment: Oh, oops. My bad.

Comment: So this means that the contraction of a maximal ideal in a localized ring is not necessarily a prime ideal in the original ring?

Comment: +1. Generalizing Alex's example: for any von Neumann regular ring, localizations at primes are all fields, but the ring itself is a domain iff it is a field (and there are many examples that aren't fields.)

Comment: @Nishant Well a maximal ideal must be prime, and the contraction of a prime ideal is always prime again. In this case our local ring is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with maximal ideal $(0)$ which then contracts to $2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ which is prime.

Comment: Wait, so if $D^{-1}Q$ is a maximal ideal of $D^{-1}B$, then $D^{-1}B/D^{-1}Q$ is a field, but this is equal to $D^{-1}(B/Q)$, so if $Q$ is in fact prime, doesn't $B/Q$ have to be an integral domain?

Comment: @Nishant, I'm not sure I quite understand, if $Q$ is a prime of $B$ then $B/Q$ is always an integral domain.

Comment: Right, but then the localization of $B/Q$ is a field, so I was trying to conclude from this that $B/Q$ must be an integral domain, but I guess I could have done it directly?

Comment: @Nishant, ah I see, yes if you knew (or could work out) that $Q$ was a prime of $B$ then it follows straight away that $B/Q$ is an integral domain, without having to try and use the statement in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to follow the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10701/if-every-prime-ideal-is-a-contracted-ideal-does-it-imply-that-the-induced-map-b?rq=1

In particular, I was trying to find the "standard argument" that $Q$ is prime.